# rails redirect after autocomplete

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have this rails-jquery-autocomplete form which works great but I would like to direct the user immediately to the city show page

```
<%= form_tag(cits_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", class: "form-inline") do %>
 <%= autocomplete_field_tag :search, params[:search], autocomplete_cit_name_events_path, 
        {class: "form-control", type: "search", 'data-auto-focus' => true} %>           
<%= submit_tag "#{t "navlinks.search"}", {class: "btn btn-default"} %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 $('#search').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
 $('#search-form').submit()
 });
</script>
```

which takes user to:

/cits?utf8=✓&search=Budapest

I would like user to arrive here:

/cits/Budapest

Which is referenced like this: cit_path(cit.name)

What magic is necessary here? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the current location instead of submitting a form.
Example:

```
$('#search').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data) {
  //First you need to get the City.
  var city = data.item.value; //or whatever key to grab the city

  //do the redirect
  window.location = '/cits/' + city;
});
```

Comment: Thansk for the quick reply. On it... But no luck grabbing the city. How do I find out whats inside the data object?

Comment: @Zsolt try doing a `console.log(data)` and show the result on the console of developer tools of your browser (on chrome or firefox just press F12)

Comment: Found it! :) "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Comment: I used it elsewhere so gave an other up :)